# get file size and split the file based on size

Tags: unix, ksh

Iam writing a korn script. I want to get the size of the file and store it in variable in the script. I dont knw how to get just the size number into the variable like if the file is of size 5GB then the variable must have 5 in it.

Also if the size of the file exceeds 5GB then it should be split into 2GB files.

Example:
Let us say the file name is File1 and the size is 5.6GB. Then the file should split into 3 files and the naming of the files should be File1, File2, File3

Can anyone help me please??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `du -BG <file>` to get the size in GB.

Hence, you can do:

```
size=$(du -BG your_file | cut -dG -f1)
```

And then

```
[ $size -ge 3 ] && split -d -b2G your_file file
```

which will give files like

```
file00
file01
```

#### Explanation

```
[ $size -ge 3 ]            &&   split -d -b2G your_file file
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  condition of size         split your_file in blocks of 2GB (-b2G)
     >=3 GB                 with name "file" with numerical suffix (-n)
```

Comment: it still is showing the file size and the file name together. I only need the file size without the name in the variable

Comment: See my `size` var definition, where I `cut` based on `G`.

Comment: okk.... i tried this one.... and seems like i get the size `du -h experiment.psv | awk '{print $1}` Now iam able to assign the output to the variable 'size'. But the output for this command is 4.0G. my requirement is i shd check the file size. If the file is greater than 3GB then it shoud be split into 2GB files. The character 'G' is getting tagged to the number. How can i compare in this case?? there is this problem again.... if the file is in MB say 834MB the the size variable contains 834.0M.

Comment: Please check my answer, as I already delt with the `G` problem with `| cut -dG -f1`.

Comment: I have changed the method now. Now iam using `stat -c%s <filename>`........ this gives me the  size of the file in bytes. The file is getting splitted now. The only thing now remaining is the name of the file. After splitting the file is splits into 3 files with names xaa, xab, xac. But i want the file name as File1, File2, File3

Comment: I have the feeling that you are not reading my answer at all. Check it, because you have the solution there.

Comment: I am really sorry. Your answer works great too. but when it comes to MB files the process gets complicated. So i turned to this method, which is working for both GB and MB files too :-) As i said the file is splitting based on the size jus like i wanted. The problem now is naming the file. Can you please help me with this?? Iam really glad for you replying me patiently. But can you help me with just this one please?? :-)

Comment: `split -d -b<size> file_name <pattern_of_new_files>` should make it. Check my answer